# c# excel how to change a color of a particular row

Tags: c#, excel, colors, row, cell

I want to ask you guys, how to change color of a row to red in Excel table if the cell 1 isn't null.

```
XX     YY     ZZ
-----------------
aa     bb     cc
aa1    bb1    cc1
aa2           cc2
aa3    bb3    cc3
aa4
```

---

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel. Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
```

I'm very thankfull

Comment: Which library you are using ?

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: I have tried    xlWorkSheet.Cells["A2", "B2"].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red); but it gives me Error COMException

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Give this a shot, I have tested it and it works:

```
Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Test\Whatever.xlsx");
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;

Excel.Range usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;

Excel.Range rows = usedRange.Rows;

int count = 0;

foreach (Excel.Range row in rows)
{
    if (count > 0)
    {
        Excel.Range firstCell = row.Cells[1];

        string firstCellValue = firstCell.Value as String;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstCellValue))
        {
            row.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }

    count++;
}

workbook.Save();
workbook.Close();

application.Quit();

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
```

Comment: I have got Error here: string firstCellValue = firstCell.Value; 
RuntimeBinderException: can't convert from double to string

Comment: 1 question more, it has changed the color of my header too, what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

```
Excel.Application xlAppToExport = new Excel.Application();
xlAppToExport.Workbooks.Add("");
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheetToExport = default(Excel.Worksheet);
xlWorkSheetToExport = (Excel.Worksheet)xlAppToExport.Sheets["Sheet1"];

xlWorkSheetToExport.Range["A5:F5"].EntireRow.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
```

Comment: It is better if you can explain how this solves the problem.