# How to set color for header or first row in excel

Tags: c#

I am reading the excel sheet as well as exporting the read excel. I want to set the Fill (backg color) color to header row of exported excel sheet.I am using C# +asp.net.

Comment: What are you using to export to Excel?

Comment: depends on the code you use for exporting, so it will be better if you show your code

Comment: Have a look [c# excel how to change a color of a particular row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725927/c-sharp-excel-how-to-change-a-color-of-a-particular-row)

Comment: if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string filename = ExcelName;
                System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
                DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
                dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
                dgGrid.DataBind();

Comment: dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
                this.EnableViewState = false;
                Response.Write(tw.ToString());
                Response.End();

Comment: this is my complete code. can anyone help.  Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to change header color of Grid or excel?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might help. Change other parameters to get the desired results.

```
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet.Range["A1","B1"].Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbDarkBlue;
```

"A" and "B" represents your range.

Hope it helps.