# Excel cells coloring

Tags: c#, excel, aspose, aspose-cells

I have this sheet in excel called **Export** and I want its header to be gray. 
Here is the code:

```
 protected void btnExcel_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      var ex = new Aspose.Cells.Workbook();
      ex.Worksheets.Clear();
      Aspose.Cells.Worksheet ws = ex.Worksheets.Add("Export");
      ws.Cells.ImportTable(Export.GetExportList(GetWhereClause(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings();
      ws.Cells[0, 0].PutValue("A");
      ws.Cells[0, 1].PutValue("B");
      ws.Cells[0, 2].PutValue("C");
      ws.Cells[0, 3].PutValue("D");
      ws.Cells[0, 4].PutValue("E");
      var style = ws.Cells.Rows[0].Style;
      style.Font.IsBold = true;
      ws.Cells.Rows[0].ApplyStyle(style, new StyleFlag { FontBold = true });
      ex.Save(string.Format("Export_{0}.xlsx", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")), FileFormatType.Excel2007Xlsx, SaveType.OpenInExcel, Response);
}
```

I included the button code as well. 
I have tried something like this:

```
style.BackgroundColor = Color.DarkGrey;
```

or

```
ws.Cells[0, 0].Style.BackgroundColor = Color.DarkGrey;
```

And I don't have the `.Interior` method.Nothing works. What can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing works"? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: have you tried setting style to cells individually? like this ws.Cells[0,0].SetStyle(style);

Comment: @haindl the lines of code I tried above. The color doesn't appear at all.

Comment: did you try the method here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696458/how-to-set-color-for-header-or-first-row-in-excel?

Comment: @Jacobr365, yes. Doesn't work.

Comment: When you say you don't have the interior method do you mean Range.Interior or Style.Interior ???

Comment: @JReid it is not Interop.Excel, it is Aspose.Cells

Comment: @JReid Style.Interior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jess Wss,

Please check the following piece of code to apply the cell shading on 1st row of the spreadsheet. Please note, there are two issues in your code.

1. In case you wish to apply the cell shading, you have to set the Style.Pattern property as well.
2. You also require to turn on the relevant StyleFlag property. In this case, the StyleFlag.CellShading has to be true before applying the style.

   ```
   var style = ws.Cells.Rows[0].Style;
   style.Font.IsBold = true;
   style.ForegroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
   style.Pattern = BackgroundType.Solid;
   ws.Cells.Rows[0].ApplyStyle(style, new StyleFlag { FontBold = true, CellShading = true });
   ```

[image]

Note: I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Colors+and+Background+Patterns

```
Style style = worksheet.Cells["A1"].GetStyle();
style.BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow;
worksheet.Cells["A1"].SetStyle(style);
```