# how to change header column colour in the generated excel

Tags: excel, export-to-excel

I am exporting data from sql server database to excel in wpf, and I have achieved the function successully. Now I want to change the head column colour in the generated excel. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = null;
        string data = null;
       // string path = null;
        //string myfilename = "Report";
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        //xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();

        xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        xlWorkSheet.Name = "Customer List";

        //connectionString = "data source=servername;initial catalog=databasename;user id=username;password=password;";
        //SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
        cnn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=ClientLists;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        cnn.Open();
        sql = "select FirstName, LastName, City, PostCode, TelephoneNo from Customers";
        SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dscmd.Fill(ds);


        for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count -1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count -1; j++)
            {
                data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = data;
            }
        }

         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range headerRange1 = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");
        headerRange1.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        headerRange1.Value = "First Name";
        headerRange1.Font.Bold = true;
        headerRange1.ColumnWidth = 14;
     // headerRange1.Interior.Color = 1;
     // headerRange1.Borders.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;


        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range headerRange2 = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("B1", "B1");
        headerRange2.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        headerRange2.Value = "Last Name";
        headerRange2.Font.Bold = true;
        headerRange2.ColumnWidth = 14;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range headerRange3 = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("C1", "C1");
        headerRange3.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        headerRange3.Value = "City";
        headerRange3.Font.Bold = true;
        headerRange3.ColumnWidth = 14;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range headerRange4 = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("D1", "D1");
        headerRange4.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        headerRange4.Value = "Post Code";
        headerRange4.Font.Bold = true;
        headerRange4.ColumnWidth = 14;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range headerRange5 = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("E1", "E1");
        headerRange5.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        headerRange5.Value = "Telephone NO";
        headerRange5.Font.Bold = true;
        headerRange5.ColumnWidth = 14;




        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();


        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
    }

    private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a post that can be found [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/621767-changing-the-column-and-row-header-color-in-excel.html) that says that this is not possible.

However, the [c# excel how to change a color of a particular row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725927/c-sharp-excel-how-to-change-a-color-of-a-particular-row) post on StackOverflow that provides code for changing a row colour... you *may* be able to adapt it for you purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed the code and the color can be changed in the above code. But now I want to add an open dialogue, I tried a lot of research in google and stackoverflow, it does not work for my app. any ideas?

Comment: @DanielXu, if you have another question, please ask it in a separate question. Please also undo your changes to this question so that other users may benefit from the answer, which makes no sense now that you have changed the question text. One further request... please mark the answer as correct if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: since I don't find the way to change the colour in the previous method, I changed the code to above and now the color can be changed. Do you think it is necessary to leave the previous code?

Comment: If you do this a lot here, you'll may kicked out of SO. Users ask questions here and other users attempt to answer those questions. You're not supposed to change the question and title if you don't get an answer you like. If you want to ask a different question, then leave the first question and ask a new question. If you get helpful information for your question, it is perfectly acceptable for you to *add* an update to your question, but you shouldn't change it, especially not completely as you have done. If I were you, I would copy your new question to a new one and undo your changes here.

Comment: Thanks for telling me. I will do as what you say. Since I am a fresh man in stackoverflow, sorry about that.

Comment: I have changed it back, I tried the link in your answer, but it is not what I want. Interior.Color changes the color of all the row area (I tried this before, this time as well), my purpose is only to change the color of the column headers(e.g. First Name..., not the whole area). Btw, I can't mark the answer now since I only have 14 reputations, it needs at least 15.

Comment: thanks for telling me so much about using stackoverflow. I got reputation when I click accept the answers(I don't know about how to accept/mark the answers before, I thought it means vote the answer...). I reviewed the questions I asked before and mark the answers if they do solve my problem. thanks again. Daniel

Comment: You're welcome and indeed, welcome to StackOverflow. You may find it helpful to read the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) here... some users are very particular about other users following the guidelines.

Comment: I upgrade the code and find a way to solve the problem in another question "how to open generated excel"! The answer provided by Sheridan is used for the whole row (Interior), it's also a good sample. Hope can help others!